# Soap post request to ASP.NET server php curl nested array

Tags: php, soap, curl

I'm facing this problem from some days but still i can't find any answer or solution either on the net or to my previous question (wich actually had some errors).

That's the scenario. I have to consume gls webservice to add parcel or list inserted parcel.
I'm using curl to construct client and make the call, here is the code from the class:

```
/*Headers*/
public function buildGlsHeaders($glsCall,$gls_lenght,$soap_action)
{       
    //header soap 1.1
    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length: " . $gls_lenght,
        $soap_action,
        );

    return $headers;
}

/*Request*/
public function sendRequest($glsCall, $requestBody, $gls_lenght, $soap_action)
{
    $cookiePath = tempnam('/tmp', 'cookie');

    //build gls headers using variables passed via constructor as well as the gls call to use
    $headers = $this->buildGlsHeaders($glsCall, $gls_lenght, $soap_action);

    //initialise a CURL session
    $connection = curl_init();

    //set the server we are using 
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://weblabeling.gls-italy.com/IlsWebService.asmx');

    //Time out
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    //set it to return the transfer as a string from curl_exec
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //stop CURL from verifying the peer's certificate
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    //set method as POST
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    //set the XML body of the request
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);

    //set the headers using the array of headers
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    //Header
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiePath);

    //Send the Request
    $response = curl_exec($connection);

    print_r(curl_getinfo($connection));

    echo "\n" . 'Header Code: ' . curl_getinfo($connection, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . "\n\n";

    //close the connection
    curl_close($connection); 

    //return the response
    return $response;
}
```

Variables $glsCall, $requestBody, $gls_lenght, $soap_action come from the script itself:

```
$soap_action = "SOAPAction: \"http://weblabeling.gls-italy.com/AddParcel\"";

$gls_lenght = strlen($xml);
```

and the request is sent by the line:

```
/*AddParcel*/
$glsResponse = $gls->sendRequest('AddParcel', $xml, $gls_lenght, $soap_action);

/*ListSped*/
$glsResponse = $gls->sendRequest('ListSped', $xml, $gls_lenght, $soap_action);
```

Now both calls are constructed in the same way, but one of them is nested:

```
$Label = array(
                'XMLInfoParcel' => array(
                'Info' => array(
                    'SedeGls' => $SedeGls,
                    'CodiceClienteGls' => $CodiceClienteGls,
                    'PasswordClienteGls' => $PasswordClienteGls,                
                    'Parcel' => array(
                                       'CodiceContrattoGls' => $cod_cont,
                                       'RagioneSociale' => $rag_soc,
                                       'Indirizzo' => $delivery_indirizzo,
                                       'Localita' => $delivery_city,
                                       'Zipcode' => $data['delivery_postcode'],
                                       'Provincia' => $data['zone_code'],
                                       'Bda' => '',
                                       'DataDocumentoTrasporto' => '',
                                       'Colli' => '1',
                                       'Incoterm' => '',
                                       'PesoReale' => '1,00',
                                       'ImportoContrassegno' => $imp_cont,
                                       'NoteSpedizione' => $data['customers_telephone'],
                                       'TipoPorto' => 'F',
                                       'Assicurazione' => $ass_ins,
                                       'PesoVolume' => '',
                                       'TipoCollo' => $tipo_collo,
                                       'FrancoAnticipata' => '',
                                       'RiferimentoCliente' => '',
                                       'NoteAggiuntive' => '',
                                       'CodiceClienteDestinatario' => '',
                                       'Email' => '',
                                       'Cellulare1' => $telefono,
                                       'Cellulare2' => '',
                                       'ServiziAccessori' => '',
                                       'ModalitaIncasso' => $mod_inc    
                                  ),),),                                
                );
```

and the other one is not:

```
/*Request*/
    $listsp = array(
                    'SedeGls' => $SedeGls,
                    'CodiceClienteGls' => $CodiceClienteGls,
                    'PasswordClienteGls' => $PasswordClienteGls 
                    );
```

those are requested input:

AddParcel

[image]

List Sped

[image]

As you can see the input format is different, here is the schema of AddParcel "string"

[image]

It continues with other fields and close with

```
       </Parcel>
  </Info>
```

ListSped call works perfectly while AddParcel doesn't, it always return a 400 Bad request header.
I assume xml is correct since i sent it to GLS IT support and they confirm me it works when uploaded directly. Unfortunatly they don't give support for php.

I was thinking about the nested array causing the problem but i don't feel like possible since if i change xml structure webservice answers correctly: "xml structure is wrong".

I've been looking around and i found some other people with the same problems but no solutions is found. I would like to make the script works in php instead of using other languages wich i don't really know anything about.

Comment: are u free right now, Fabio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in picture 'AddParcel' of requested input the input itself is a string.

I realized that it wants it to be formatted as:

```
    &lt;Info&gt;&lt;SedeGls&gt;XXX&lt;/SedeGls&gt;&lt;CodiceContrattoGls&gt;XXX&lt;/CodiceContrattoGls&gt; <!--and so on-->
```